# How to perform a sensitivity analysis in Bayesian statistics?

Tags: bayesian, inference, prior

Bayesian inference is drawn from the posterior distribution or - in case we are interested in forecasting - from the predictive posterior distribution. However, these values are heavily affected by the choice of the prior, even if you have decided to go for an uninformed one (which can be implemented in many different ways). Is there a standard way to convince the audience that your choice of the prior does not lead your results a priori in a way that would diminish the value of your results (Of course your results are affected by informed priors, but slight changes in your prior should - at least in my intuition - not lead to extreme changes in the results.)? Could this problem be relaxed by the choice of hierarchical models because it also implies 'switching' priors?
I am happy for each and every comment or reference on how this problem can be tackled,thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A fairly standard approach to showing that your results were not heavily influenced by your choice of prior is simply to show that your results hold when choosing a different prior. For example, if you have an informed prior that suggests a certain result is more likely, you might want to also show your results also hold when a uniform prior is specified.

A fairly new piece of software for checking such things is called [JASP](https://jasp-stats.org/), which is like a free, modern SPSS that handles Bayesian versions of many frequentest statistical tests. What is nice about this, is that when you run a Bayesian test it outputs a graph showing what your test result would have been had a range of other priors been specified. I don't know if this output is something you would want to include in a report, but it is useful to get an idea of how sensitive your results were to your specific prior.